# API for server-side encryption configuration of an S3 object

Tags: object, encryption, amazon-s3

I do see we have an API to get encryption for a bucket but however I see that the bucket can have different encryption to the object under the bucket. I am looking to find a way (API) to get the encryption details of the object.

Answer (score 0):

**getObject method in javascript SDK will return the details related to object in a bucket. returned data will have ServerSideEncryption property to get the encryption that is applied to object**

```
function getAttachment(fileName){
    var params ={
        Bucket: "ascendon1", 
        Key: fileName
    }
    return s3.getObject(params).promise();
}


app.post('/downloadFiles',function(req,res){

    var promises =[];
    var filesContent = [];
    var filesToDownload = req.body.fileNames
    for(var z=0; z<req.body.fileNames.length;z++){
        var fileName = filesToDownload[z];
        promises.push(getAttachment(fileName));
    }

    Promise.all(promises).then(function(data){
        for(var z=0; z<req.body.fileNames.length;z++){
            var contents={
                filename: filesToDownload[z],
                content: data[z].Body,
                //Server side encryption details of object 
                encryption:data[z].ServerSideEncryption
            };
            filesContent.push(contents);
        }
        console.log(filesContent);

    }).catch(function(error){
        console.log(error.stack);
    })

})
```

here is the output:

[image: output]

Comment: I am using golang SDK. The returned object doesn't have ServerSideEncryption property

Comment: what is the version of the SDK you are using ?

Comment: v1.12.70 aws-sdk-go